# How to lemmatize Norwegian using spaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, lemmatization

I'm doing the following:

```
from spacy.lang.nb import Norwegian
nlp = Norwegian()
doc = nlp(u'Jeg heter Marianne Borgen og jeg er ordføreren i Oslo.')
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_,token.shape_, token.is_alpha, token.is_stop)
```

Lemmatization seems to not work at all, as this is the output:

```
(u'Jeg', u'Jeg', u'', u'', u'', u'Xxx', True, False)
(u'heter', u'heter', u'', u'', u'', u'xxxx', True, False)
(u'Marianne', u'Marianne', u'', u'', u'', u'Xxxxx', True, False)
(u'Borgen', u'Borgen', u'', u'', u'', u'Xxxxx', True, False)
(u'og', u'og', u'', u'', u'', u'xx', True, True)
(u'jeg', u'jeg', u'', u'', u'', u'xxx', True, True)
(u'er', u'er', u'', u'', u'', u'xx', True, True)
(u'ordf\xf8reren', u'ordf\xf8reren', u'', u'', u'', u'xxxx', True, False)
(u'i', u'i', u'', u'', u'', u'x', True, True)
(u'Oslo', u'Oslo', u'', u'', u'', u'Xxxx', True, False)
(u'.', u'.', u'', u'', u'', u'.', False, False)
```

However, looking at https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/nb/lemmatizer/_verbs_wordforms.py, the verb *heter* should at least be transformed into *hete*.

So it looks like spaCy has support, but it's not working? What could be the problem?

Comment: It seems that the model for Norwegian is still being developed. Maybe that's the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lemmatization does in fact work for Norwegian as it's specified in the [docs](https://spacy.io/usage/adding-languages#lemmatizer): all forms in [lookup.py](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/nb/lemmatizer/lookup.py) are lemmatized. Try for instance `doc = nlp(u'ei')` and you'll see that the lemma of `ei` is `en`.

Now, the file you are referring to, `verbs_wordforms.py`, documents exceptions in case the part-of-speech (POS) tag is a verb. However, the blank model `Norwegian()` does not have a POS tagger and so that particular exception for `heter` is never triggered.

So the solution is either to use a model which has a POS tagger, or to add your specific exceptions to `lookup.py`. You'll see for instance that if you'd add there the line `'heter': 'hete',` that your blank model would find `hete` as lemma for `heter`.

Finally, note that there's been a lot of [work and discussion](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3082) about publishing a pre-trained Norwegian model in spaCy - but it looks like that is still a bit of a work in progress.